# Как сделать уведомления по конкретному времени в Android?

Tags: android, время, push-уведомления

Я делаю приложения для класса, там расписание уроков, расписание звонков, заметки для дз и калькулятор.

Мне надо сделать так чтобы уведомления выводились по определенному времени. То есть например: **До урока осталось 5 мин** или **Урок закончится через 2 минуты**

Я смотрел все статьи на похожую тему, но не и понял, так как плохо в чтении кода и не понимаю что к чему.

Вот код класса "Расписание звонков" там я реализовываю уведомления:

```
package com.example.list;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import static androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH;

public class ScheduleOfCalls extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 1;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Расписание Звонков";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.schedule_of_calls);


        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ScheduleOfCalls.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

                NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                                .setAutoCancel(false)
                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_icon_tson)
                                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setContentTitle("Расписание Звонков")
                                .setContentText("Осталось 5 мин до урока")
                                .setPriority(PRIORITY_HIGH);

                createChannelIfNeeded(notificationManager);
                notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notificationBuilder.build());
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createChannelIfNeeded(NotificationManager manager) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_ID, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    public void Button_back(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
    public void Button_AA(View view) {
        Intent AA = new Intent(ScheduleOfCalls.this, AboutApp.class);
        startActivity(AA);
    }
}
```

В коде я использовал кнопку, но её я уберу. Так что на кнопку не обращайте внимание.

Я буду благодарен, если вы будете объяснять примером кода, а не типа вот эту функцию туда, это сюда и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Я смогу только дать подсказку, куда нужно копать. А копать нужно в сторону WorkManager.

Создаёте какую то задачу в WorkManager'е

Comment: Я почитал о WorkManager'е и понял что это не вариант. Мне нужно как минимум AlarmManager, но я не знаю как его реализовать

Answer (score 0):

вам нужен workmanager. Вот урок:  https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/562-urok-29-workmanager-vvedenie.html